# Как отобразить медиа файлы, загруженные через админ. панель в django?

Tags: python, html, django

Не получается отобразить изображение, загруженное через админ. панель в джанго

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',  # медиа
            ],
        },
    },
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets/media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

В папке assets/media изображения после загрузки появились.

Код в шаблоне:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{p.img.url}}" alt="">
<img src="{{p.img.url}}" alt="">
```

При переходе по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/myimage.png изображение тоже не отображается

UPD: добавил в urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [ ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

И заработало. Это какой-то костыль? При deploy это оставлять или менять нужно будет?

Answer (score 1):

Разницы, как и где вы загружаете файл на сервер, нет, админ-панель - просто дефолтная страница для работы с бд из браузера, точно так же вы можете ручками из СУБД создать новую запись, разницы не будет.

То, что вы сделали, не совем костыль. Вот [ссылка](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/) на доки, там всё расписано. По-хорошему, это только для разработки, но по своему опыту знаю, что иногда это и на проде оставляют.

Answer (score 0):

В корне, где лежит `settings` в `urls`, в низу где-нибудь добавит:

```
urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```